# In Subgradient descent method for convex problem: can we say $x^{(k)} \approx x^{(k-1)}$ for iteration $k \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, subgradient

Apologies for the basic question.

Let us say that the general convex problem is
$$\min_x f(x).$$

Say, we employ a subgradient method 
$$x^{(k)} = x^{(k-1)} - t_k \partial f\left( x^{(k-1)}\right) ,$$
where $t_k$ is a step-size and $\partial f$ is a subgradient.

**Question**: Can we say $x^{(k)} \approx x^{(k-1)}$ for iteration $k \rightarrow \infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless the step size $t_k$ decays to $0$. Otherwise, you can take $f(x) = |x|$ as a counterexample. For example, suppose at iteration $k$ you are at $x = 1$. Then the sub-gradient of $f$ at $x$ is $1$. If $t_k = 2$ (for all $k$), then the update rule says $x^{(k+1)} = 1 - (2)(1) = -1$. Now, the sub gradient is $-1$ and the update rule says
$$x^{(k+2)} = -1 - (2)(-1) = 1$$
In other words, the iterations keep bouncing between $\pm 1$ and never converge.

When $t_k \to 0$, then gradient descent will converge to the minimum of the convex function $f$, and so $x^{(k)}$ will be approximately $x^{(k+1)}$.

However, you usually need the assumption that $f$ is at least Lipschitz in order to prove results on how long it takes for this convergence to occur.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. So, if $f$ is Lipschitz then can I say $\nabla f(x^{(k+1)}) \approx \nabla f(x^{(k)})$ when $k \rightarrow \infty $? If yes, then what theorem/lemma shall it be?

Comment: This is not actually true even if $f$ is Lipschitz! What you can say is that $f(x^{(k+1)}) \approx f(x^{(k)})$ and you can get some bounds on how fast this occurs. There are a lot of different results depending on what you want... maybe this will help? https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee392o/subgrad_method.pdf

Comment: Aha, ok. thank you. But if I have a condition that $f$ is differentiable with Lipschitz continuous gradient, then can we say $\nabla f(x^{(k+1)}) \approx \nabla f(x^{(k)})$? or is it still not true and the should condition be $ f(x^{(k+1)}) \approx f(x^{(k)})$?

Comment: Yes in this case because when $f$ is differentiable, the solution $x^*$ to the convex optimization problem satisfies $\nabla f(x^*) = 0$ (the derivative is zero at the optimum). So the gradients of the iterations approach zero. In the literature, the condition you mentioned is usually referred to as smooth convex optimization.